# visibility of a class data member in a nested class?

Tags: c++, c++11

AFAIK, data member of enclosing class are also visible in nested class.

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        int arr[n];  // how come n is not visible here, but it is visible in next statement.
        int x = n;
    };

    static const int n = 5;
};
```

[see live demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/zvrhqjdn6)

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: Because `int x = n;` is complete class context.

Comment: Interesting; `int arr[A::n];` compiles with latest `msvc` but not with `gcc`.

Comment: @JasonLiam what does it mean ? but if we declare  n before the starting of nested class , it work fine.

Comment: @273K why we cant declare arr[n] ?

Comment: @mn_op If you were to declare `n` before the nested class, then name lookup can find `n` and so that works. But when you declare it after the nested class, name lookup can't find it and also it is not in a complete class context.

Comment: @JasonLiam The OP probably meant: why `n` is undefined when used in array definition while it is defined when assigned to x. In both cases, `static const int n = 5;` is defined after it is called.

Comment: @RohanBari `int a = n;` works because it is a complete class context and c++ standard allows it. On the other hand, `int arr[n];` is not complete class context and c++ standard doesn't allow it.

Comment: @JasonLiam when we use fully qualified name for a, it works on msvc. [https://godbolt.org/z/5MTPTh8Ks] see here.

Comment: @mn_op That seems to be a compiler bug.

Comment: @mn_op Complete class context (which applies to the default-initializer, but not the type, of a non-static member) means that name lookup is done from it as if the ending `}` of the class had already been reached. So it then doesn't matter how the declaration of `n` is ordered.

Comment: @mn_op Here is the [msvc bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-compiles-invalid-program-when-using/10207790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how come n is not visible here, but it is visible in next statement.

Because `int x = n;` is a complete class context while `int arr[n];` is not. This can be understood from [class.mem](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem#6) which states:

> **6)** A **complete-class context** of a class is a:
>
> **6.4)** **default member initializer**
>
> within the member-specification of the class.
> [ Note: A complete-class context of a nested class is also a complete-class context of any enclosing class, if the nested class is defined within the member-specification of the enclosing class.
> — end note
> ]
>
> **7)** A class is considered a completely-defined object type ([basic.types]) (or complete type) at the closing } of the class-specifier. **The class is regarded as complete within its complete-class contexts**; otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification.

(emphasis mine)

Note that the `n` inside `int arr[n];` is **part of the type of the array but the above quoted statement doesn't allow `n` to be used as part of a type of a non-static data member** and hence the error. For the same reason, we will get the same error if we wrote:

```
struct A {
    struct B {
          
        int x = n;
//----------------------v--------->same error as before
        std::array<int, n> arr; 
    };

    static constexpr int n = 5;
};
```

Comment: The quoted part of the standard seems to explain what a "complete-class context" is, but not *why* being complete-class context or not implies `n` being visible or not in this or that expression. Should also [#7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem#7) be quoted for completeness? Specifically _The class is regarded as complete within its complete-class contexts_?

Comment: @Enlico Added your suggestion for completeness(pun intended)

Comment: @JasonLiam then how come we can use ``n`` as a part of the type of the array in member function body ? [https://godbolt.org/z/jGnqEj99e] see demo here.

Comment: @mn_op The body of a function is also a complete-class context: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.mem#6.1

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more like intuition of why this is so:

In `int arr[n]` n is used in definition of a filed, while in `int x = n` n is used to initialize a field. It is like `B() : x(n) {}`.

Think of the following example:

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        int arr[n];
        int x = n;
    };
    static constexpr int n = offsetof(B, x);
};
```

Here the value of `n` is dependent on the size of `arr` and size of the arr is dependent on `n`. It is a cross dependency. Therefore the `struct` is not well defined.

If the rules of the C++ was so that your use case be legal, then this should also be legal, which can't be. However, it still allow us to use `offsetof` in initialization, because why not?

Answer (score -3):

Something about evaluation variable in left-hand side of assignment, not a computer language expert, the following worked.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    struct A {
        struct B {
            int *arr = new int[n]();
            int x = n;
        };
    
        static const int n = 5;
    };
    int main() {
      cout << "Hello World!";
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is not looking for a workaround.